# Switching a 4-lane bus under microcontroller supervision

Tags: usb, switches, bus

Looking for a simple and effective way to switch a 4-lane bus, under the control of a microcontroller (labelled as "controller"), as shown in the logical schematic below. Device-3 should be connected to Device-1 or Device-2 at any given point in time.

[image: Logical schematic]

I am pretty sure that something like this, i.e. switching a bus, is pretty commonplace in electronics design. The bus in question is basically USB ! So we have +5V, GND, D+ and D- (5V logic). Also, Device-1 and Device-2 are "USB hostss", while Device-3 is playing the role of "USB device".

Would appreciate hints / suggestions along 2 lines / approaches -

1. All PTH, hobby grade, using simple to source components, i.e. no specialized ICs, apart from a common microcontroller (say ATtiny45).
2. Somewhat more compact (less component count), elegant and modern approach (but hopefully without SMD components).

For the 1st approach, I was thinking of using a pair of FET or BJT's (*) on the D+/D- lines for each of the devices (Device-1 and Device-2), with 1 GPIO pin controlling each pair. The +5V and GND stay always connected to both devices though, I am not sure, what it means from the USB protocol standpoint, as D+/D- are always pulled low.

If someone would like to know what I am trying to achieve, then it is a crude (but hopefully effective) switchover of a USB external hard-disk between 2 PC's, as a form of failover.

(*) *I have many general-purpose BJT's in my hobby-stock, and no FET. So unless it is really an issue, I'd prefer using BJT's.*

Comment: You are unlikely to be happy with trying to switch a USB device that way.

Comment: To expand on @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams's comment, you cannot switch USB this way. USB requires sequencing of the power and data connections, to properly reset the devices. You cannot just leave the power lines connected, as may devices will not properly re-enumerate when reconnected, as they rely on a power-cycle to reinitialize their state.

Comment: Okay, then how about I switch power as well ?

Comment: USB might have *originally* been intended for sequencing but that is clearly not provided in any meaningful way by the miniature connectors now popular on the device end.  Passive switching with FET pass gates might be workable for low or full speed but it will be challenging to maintain impedance to cleanly support high speed as would be desired for a disk drive.  If you want to try, use FET bus switches with as near as possible to zero cable length from the drive.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thanks for taking time to comment. It might qualify as an answer :-)

Comment: Looked up "2:1 Quad Mux/Demux IC", and came up against IC's like NXP's CBT3257A or OnSemi's 74FST3257 or TI's SN74CBTLV3257 etc. Would those do ? They come closes to what I interpret and imagine the possibility to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a given generic multiplexer or bus switch might work, USB has high bandwidth, bidirectional data lines with certain terminating and series resistance requirements that make them a bad choice. Luckily, **usb switch** ics are plentiful.

The [TI TS3USB30E](http://www.ti.com/product/ts3usb30e) for example, is a 1:2 High Speed USB 2.0 multiplexer switch. It has a single switch pin (High/Low) and an Output Enable pin, which drives the lines into a High Impedance mode, allowing the attached devices to disconnect if needed. And it is available in a SOP sized chip, not leadless quadpacks or bga. Frankly, you won't find many suitable USB Switches in DIP/Throughhole, the best you will find are relatively easy to solder SMD SOIC and SOP packages.

If you really find that you need to switch power as well, a P-Channel fet or PNP transistor on the 5v line. Ground you could keep connected. If you feel fancy, there are tons of **usb power switches**

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can switch an USB bus with four relays, it's not standard but it works, I built the very same application a few years ago. It worked and was perfectly reliable. The trick is to connect the power first, then the data lines. But I don't think doing this with BJT's nor fets is a great idea: you need isolation.

I think one of the quickest/easiest to build this is to use USB controlled relays, which are very common. For instance:

www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-actuators/yocto-relay

www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=9